# Putting an image on the top of all elements

Tags: html, css, forms

I have made a horizontal opt-in bar for my Newsletter on my website.

The points is that I have replaced the submit button for an image using CSS:

```css
#mc_embed_signup input.button {
background: url(http://urltotheimg.com/image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: none;
position: absolute!important;
left: 720px;
top: -15px;
width: 120px!important;
height: 120px!important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form class="validate" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" action="**here I put the action to suscribe**" method="post" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" novalidate="" target="_blank">
<div class="mc-field-group">
<font color="white" size="4">¡Empieza a triunfar en Internet!</font><input class="required" id="mce-FNAME" type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="Tu nombre (sin apellidos)" value="" />
<input class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Tu email" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form></div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

But for some reason, the button gets cropped on the top.

Do you know how could I fix this? Thank you so much.

EDIT: 
Since I can´t post images yet, you can have a look of how it looks on the website itself: http://javierferrandez.com

Comment: Its hard to tell as you haven't provided the image file but could it be the `top: -15px` in your CSS thats the issue? If you can provide the image (or any image that has the same dimensions) then I could help further. Also a screenshot of the issue you are experiencing would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, sorry but since I have no reputation yet I can´t post images.

You can check it here: http://javierferrandez.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the **.container** *div* element, wrapping the form..

property, `overflow:hidden` is resulting this issue.

just remove it..!

change below rules, page will be set..!

```
//reduced width & min-width to make things nice.!
.mc-field-group {
    background-color: #F68D31;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 1000px;
    min-width: 1000px;
}
//removed overflow property below
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 1140px;
}
```

[image: Please check the linked Image!]

---

### Making element to fit to total width & centered

Add this css!

```
selector {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Please take a note of below styling

```
.layout-boxed .outer-container, .container {
max-width: 1000px; /*Remove this property*/
}

.container {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1140px; /* Remove this property too */
overflow: hidden;
}
```

### Add below properties

```
#mc_embed_signup {
background-color: #F68D31; /*Added background-color*/
}

.mc-field-group {
background-color: #F68D31; /*You can remove the background here */
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 850px; /*This should be fixed one, but value can be of your own */
}

#mc_embed_signup input.button {
background: url(http://javierferrandez.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/equis-e1415619436433.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
top: -15px;
border: none;
position: absolute !important;
/* right: 250px; */ /*Removed it */
width: 120px!important;
height: 120px!important;
margin-left: 20px; /*Newly added property */
}
```

Comment: That definitely worked! Thank you so Much YaswanthJg.

Just one little thing, do you know how could I make the bar to be full width? I want it to cover the whole website, as the slider. Thanks so much for your response!

Comment: @Viccino..! Make width as 100%

Comment: @Viccino
remove max-width & width values for the div with class 'container', parent of '#mc_embed_signup'.
`.layout-boxed .outer-container, .container {
max-width: 1000px;
}` & `.container { width:1140px;}`......... AND.... give the fixed width rather than 'percentage'

Answer (score 1):

i cant see whats happening in your example, but the `top: -15px` combined with absolute position is going to chop off some of your button at the top of the screen.  change to `top: 0;` to make it right at the top, or a positive value to move it down.

```
#mc_embed_signup input.button {
background: url(http://urltotheimg.com/image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: none;
position: absolute!important;
left: 720px;
top: 0;
width: 120px!important;
height: 120px!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Erik. When I change that "top" thing, the button goes down in a weird position. I might need something to place it up without chopping it.

Comment: left: controls where it appears from the left of the screen.  If you set it to 0, and top to 0, you can change your values from there.  You also don't have to use absolute positioning, if you want it to appear in your page flow as it appears in your code dont use absolute.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code below and let me know if this works for you.

In css, remove the position :absolute and top:-15px attributes and add margin-top:20px;

```
<div class="mc-field-group">
<div><input class="required" id="mce-FNAME" type="text" name="FNAME" value="" />
<input class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" type="email" name="EMAIL" value="" /></div>
<input type="submit" value="" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Thanks